# Use 's' instead of 'self' as the first parameter of python method, is this good?

Tags: python, self

```
class actor:
    def __init__(s, own, *arg, name:str, **karg):
        s.gv=own.gv; s.own=own; s.name=name; own.sub[s.name]=s; s.sub=dict()
        s._setup_(*arg, **karg)
```

This is part of my code. i often use s instead of self to shrink the code.

Comment: Not a good practice but the compiler won't throw any error

Comment: it's not "wrong", but it goes against universal convention and is therefore more or less guaranteed to confuse those who read your code. Not to mention it's much less descriptive - 1-letter variable names are almost universally a bad idea, with the common exception of "counter" variables in loops.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: There is no prize for the shortest code :-) I suggest that you use `self` per normal convention, **and** put one statement per line instead of the semicolons. Fewer lines does not always mean quicker to read.

Comment: I've been moving all of my code to sanskrit, so `def __init__(स्वाध्याय, ...)`. Needless to say, code reviews have  been contentious.

Comment: Sometimes i'm using Chinese characters as variable name.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not good. [PEP8 states that `self` should always be used](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments):

> Always use self for the first argument to instance methods.
>
> Always use cls for the first argument to class methods.

Trying to neaten code by resorting to more obscure names may save you *tens* of keystrokes, but it will ultimately make your code harder to read.

When you follow common, standardized conventions (like using `self`), that's one less thing someone reading your code will need to interpret. If you're reading code and you see `self`, you know that it's referring to the instance object being worked on. It's implicit. You don't even need to look at the parameters to see that.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but the readability of your code comes down when you tend to not follow the general convention. You wouldn't face any error though.

Answer (score 0):

While this will work and shrink the code, this makes it harder to read (in my opinion), and will cause problems if you ever use "s" as a variable - which is much more common than "self".

Comment: i've marked s as a keyword in my ide, so this is not a big problem when i'm the only programmer in my organisation.

Comment: @Milowork *so what are you asking?*

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks), the use of **self** is only a convention, but it is **highly recommended to follow the convention**:

> Often, the first argument of a method is called **self**. This is
> nothing more than a convention: the name **self** has absolutely no
> special meaning to Python. Note, however, that by not following the
> convention your code may be less readable to other Python programmers,
> and it is also conceivable that a class browser program might be
> written that relies upon such a convention.

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id46) also recommends naming the first argument **self**:

> Always use **self** for the first argument to instance methods.